# Setting tabstop (keyboard accessibility) for grid controls in Xaml

Tags: xaml, accessibility, tabstop

I have a Xaml page that has a bunch of different grids within grids.  The page has 3 main "buttons" for a user to click.  I want to allow a user using just a keyboard to tab through and select these 3 buttons, however because they are grid's, they do not have a tabstop.  Anyone have a suggestion how I achieve this without a complete redesign of the page using something other than grids (such as buttons)?

Comment: By "design" do you mean software design, or graphic design? If it's just graphic design, make those elements Buttons -- or any other control that has a Click event and can accept keyboard focus -- and give them templates that make them *look* like grids.

Comment: Yea this is confusing. Grid's aren't tabstop's and FocusManager will only iterate through elements which accept focus.